# Displaying score overlapping

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, uilabel, cocos2d-x

I used cocos2d game tutorial from http://www.raywenderlich.com/25736/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial After i add the score to scorelabel, the score increases but the previous score isn't getting removed and the new score gets added above the earlier score's label

code:

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CCLabelTTF * label1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"_monsterdestroyed" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:32];
score=score + 2;

[label1 setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score]];

label1.color = ccc3(0,0,0);
label1.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
[self addChild:label1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are doing all this in an update method, adding a label1 label at every update. You probably want an iVar in your .h file for the score label1 , initialize it in your init, as follows:

in .h

```
CCLabelTTF *label1;
```

in .m

```
-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // your existing code, add the following
        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        label1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:32];
        label1.color = ccc3(0,0,0);
        label1.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:label1];  
   }     
 }


 // where you update the score
 score = score + 2;
 [label1 setSting:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%i", score];
```